# cardinality of power set of the following set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$$\{6, 18, 54,..., 6561\}$$
This is a GP with $$a = 6, r=3, T_n=6561.$$
Solving for n is coming out to be fractional.
How to solve for n?

Comment: If its coming fractional, then I think it's not a term in the GP

Comment: The series is wrong, it should be 6,18,54.......,4374,13122

Comment: yes, I think there is a mistake in printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the problem doesn’t make sense because $6(3)^6 = 4374 < 6561$ and $6(3)^7 = 13122 > 6561$. Taking the logarithm you’d expect $T_n$ to be about the $7.6$th term, but that’s of course impossible.

Comment: thanks just wanted to confirm if it is wrong